# No Non trivial subgroup means prime order?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a group with more than one element, $G$ had no proper, non-trivial subgroup then prove that $|G|$ is prime.

Attempt.

> **Claim**
>
> **$G$ is finite**
>
> If not then for any $x\neq e$ we have $\langle x^2 \rangle$ a non-trivial subgroup of $G$.
>   Hence $G$ is finite.
>
> Now given $G$ is finite.Let $|G|=m$
>   For any $x\neq e$ we have $\langle x \rangle$ a subgroup of $G$.
>
> Now because there exists no non trivial subgroup,
>   we have $\langle x\rangle=G$
>
> Hence $G=\langle x \rangle$
>
> Hence $G$ is cyclic.
>
> How do I show that $|G|$ is prime?

Kindly do not use Cauchy Theorem.
Use Lagrange's Theorem only, or topics taught before Lagrange Theorem.

Comment: What if $x^2=e?$ That's possible when $G$ is infinite. It's even possible for it to be true for all $x\in G.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews then you would have a subgroup of order $2$, therefore non-trivial and proper ($\left<x\right>$).

Comment: Sure, but that's not what the argument said. @ArnaudMortier

Comment: I believe that it was implied.

Comment: The usual argument starts by proving (as you have done later) that $G$ is cyclic and then arguing (as you have done) that $G$ must be finite.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier A person learning math shouldn't skip steps. An important step here is stating for any $x\neq e,$ $\langle x\rangle =G.$ So $\langle x\rangle$ is infinite, and hence $\langle x^2\rangle$ is a proper subgroup.

Comment: @user567182 Sure, but your proof that $G$ is finite is incomplete. And $\langle x \rangle = G$ is a useful statement for both the finite and infinite cases.

Answer (score 4):

For any $x\in G$, $x\neq e$ we must have $\langle x\rangle=G$, since $H=\langle x\rangle$ is a subgroup, and $H\neq \{e\}$.

Now, if $x^2=e$, we have $G=\langle x\rangle=\{e,x\},$ a cyclic group of order $2$.

If $x^2\neq e$ then $\langle x^2\rangle=G$, too, so $x=(x^2)^k$ for some $k,$ and hence $x^{2k-1}=e$ for some $k.$ In particular, $G=\langle x\rangle$ is finite.

If $x$ is of order $n$ where $n$ is not prime, say $n=ab,$ with $a,b>1.$ Then $\langle x^a\rangle\neq G.$

So, we must have $n$ prime, and we are done.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the usual complete argument.

Let $x\in G$, with $x \ne e$. Then $\langle x \rangle$ is a nontrivial subgroup and so must be $G$, that is, $G=\langle x \rangle$.

If $G=\langle x \rangle$ is infinite, then $\langle x^2 \rangle$ is a proper subgroup. Therefore, $G$ is finite.

Thus, $G=\langle x \rangle$ is cyclic of order $m$. If $m=ab$, with $a,b>1$, then $\langle x^a \rangle$ is a proper, non-trivial subgroup.
Therefore, $m$ is prime.

Comment: This assumes $G$ is finite.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, my answer was a continuation of the OP's argument. I've added the complete argument.